# Running bash script after reboot

Tags: bash, cron, reboot

I would like to run the following script after reboot

```
username$ screen

username$ while true; do php cron.php; sleep 5; done
```

Then i'll create another screen session to run another one

```
username$ while true; do php cron2.php; sleep 5; done
```

usually I use cron to do that, but I want to do that every 5 seconds.

is there anyway to do even after the system reboot?

Comment: The cron entry for at startup would be `@reboot /path/to/script`

Comment: What is `$username`?

Comment: Sorry I meant to type username$

Comment: @Terrance I'm not using cron!!

Comment: OK, so you would just add that to your startup is all.  I don't see anything complicated with what you're doing.   By the way, the `@reboot` when added to the cron only runs at startup and never again until the next reboot.

Comment: @JackSmith OK, what's `username$`? Your PS1? Why is your PS1 in the script?

Comment: Can I run this command on system startup? `while true; do php cron2.php; sleep 5; done`